# SQL Assign Unique number to each unique value in a column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in Snowflake with people's names and other attributes. To simplify, it looks like the table below.

[image]

How can I add a new column with assigned unique number to each person directly to the table using SQL? 
The ideal result is like below

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dense_rank()`:

```
select name, dense_rank() over (order by name) as uniquenum
from t;
```

You can use this logic in an `update`, but the exact syntax depends on the database.